# Defining prototype functions for a class inside IIFE, while forcing "new"

Tags: javascript, function, class, oop, object

Consider the following code:

```js
var a = (function()
{
  function a(str)
  {
    if(!(this instanceof a))
      return new a(str);

    console.log('a created with str: ' + str);
  }

  a.prototype.b = function()
  {
    console.log('a.b called');
  }

  return a;
})();

console.log(a);
a('asd');
a.b();
```

First, the IIFE's execution defines the class `a`, with a `prototype` method `b`. It then `return`s the constructor for the class, which is stored in `var a`. This is confirmed by the fact that `console.log(a);` displays the code for the constructor in the console, and `a('asd');` correctly results in a log message saying `a created with str: asd`.

What I don't understand is why does the line `a.b();` result in an `Uncaught TypeError: a.b is not a function` error? Why isn't the `a.prototype` definition carrying over to `var a`? And how can I get it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why does the line a.b(); result in an Uncaught TypeError: a.b is not
>   a function

It is because the inner a function is only executed on the line

```
a('asd');
```

but this line returns a reference to the `new a` instance which you never store, so you have no access to a prototype methods.

Look at the below modified snippet.

```js
var a = (function()
{
  function a(str)
  {
    if(!(this instanceof a))
      return new a(str);

    console.log('a created with str: ' + str);
  }

  a.prototype.b = function()
  {
    console.log('a.b called');
  }

  return a;
})();

console.log(a);
let c = a('asd'); // Here a holds a reference to inner a and inner a is now called, prototype b added
// a.b(); error, there is no b of (outer) a
c.b(); // This is now OK
```